# php mysql query with multiple params and get individual results per

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to think of a way to form a query where I can query for each parameter I need, and get the results back on a per param basis. Ive tried a combination of AND/OR but not getting the expected results.

the basis of the query I wanna do is to the extent of

```
select fb_wall, fb_checkin, phone 
from member_prefs where 
memeberid = 21 
OR memeberid = 22 
OR memeberid = 23 
OR memeberid = 24
```

The catch is, I need to either ignore when one of the memberid's doesnt have data and keep the query going (or catch the id, so if one is found I can add the row for it in another query after the fact but still keep the query going).

Right now my dummy data is 3 out of the 4 memberid's have data and one doesn't if I do AND in the query, the query stops and yields no results. Where as if I do the OR i seem to only be returning one of there sets of data.

What I want to do is after the query build an array to pass around that would look like

```
array(
   [0] array("memberid"=>21, "fb_wall"=>0, "fb_checkin"=>1, "phone"=>0),
   [1] array("memberid"=>22, "fb_wall"=>1, "fb_checkin"=>0, "phone"=>1),
   [2] array("memberid"=>24, "fb_wall"=>1, "fb_checkin"=>1, "phone"=>1)
)
```

just seem to be having a little issue forming the initial query, and like I said if I could in this case pass 23 else where so I could run an insert command on that id for the same table that would be awesome but not needed for the over all need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
//parameter data
$members = array(
    22 => null,
    23 => null,
    24 => null,
    25 => null
);
//make a comma separated list of ids
$ids = implode(',', array_keys($members));
//generate query text
$sql = '
    select memberid, fb_wall, fb_checkin, phone 
    from   member_prefs 
    where  memberid in ('.$ids.')
';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $members[$row[0]] = $row;    
}
```

Comment: Ok, Im pretty much copying this for all its worth my query
`select mID, fb_wall, fb_checkin, phone from memb_prefs where mID in(21,22,23,24)`  and my output miss match, 21 should have a set of results as well but is null `{"status":"success","msg":{"21":null,"22":["22","1","1","1"],"23":["23","0","3","2"],"24":null}} `

Comment: What do you mean, "should have set of results"? Do you mean it should be: "21": [null, null, null, null] ? If so, simply initialize $members accordingly: $nulls = array(null, null, null, null); $members = array(22 => $nulls, 23 => $nulls, ...);

Comment: 21 should have had 3,3,3 as its result at the time, I have since come up with a better means of forming the data so I can pass it around and work with it accordingly. However the initial basis of your answer helped me out greatly in the cause, so I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

Start with an array with the relevant keys, and replace the elements as you read the rows.

```
$ares = array(21 => null, 22 => null, 23 => null, 24 => null);
```

Comment: that definately helps, but its the query currently that is still causing me headache, at best I only get a single result it seems and its far from distinguishable as to which user it specific to